# Structure of RKHS induced by a Gaussian kernel

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, machine-learning, reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

I am studying Reproducing Kernel Hilbert Space, in the context of Maximum Mean Discrepancy. The following points summarize what I've understood up to now

- If $X$ is a set, $H$ Hilbert space, then $k: X \times X \to \mathbb{R}$ is a **reproducing kernel** if the reproducing property holds, i.e. for every $ x \in X $, for every $ f \in H$
  \begin{equation}
   \langle f, k ( \cdot , x) \rangle _ H = f (x)  \end{equation}
- A function $k: X \times X \to \mathbb{R}$ is a **kernel** iff exists $H $ Hilbert space and $\phi :X \to H $ such that \begin{equation}k(x , y ) = \langle{\phi( x ) }, {\phi ( y) } \rangle_H \end{equation}
- From these definitions, a reproducing kernel in a RKHS $ H $ is clearly a kernel, with associated
  feature map $ \phi ( x) = k ( \cdot , x ) $. Conversely, each positive definite function $ k ( x , y)  $ can be associated to an unique RKHS H, which has k as its reproducing kernel (Moore-Aronszajn them)

So my question is the following. Suppose to simply consider $ k : X \times X \to \mathbb R  $ as $ k ( x_ 1, x _2 ) = e ^ {- \frac{ \|{x_ 1  - x_ 2  } \|
 ^ 2} {2 \sigma ^ 2 } }$, the Gaussian kernel, and consider the same kernel, but defined  on another space  $Y $, so $ k :Y \times Y \to \mathbb R $ as $ k ( y_ 1, y _2 ) = e ^ {- \frac{ \|{ y_ 1  - y_ 2  } \|
 ^ 2} {2 \sigma ^ 2 } }$, with other properties and a priori very different (within a ML context, you can think of X as **feature** space and Y as **label** space).

What is the relationship between the two and do they induce the same RKHS? Namely, if $ H ' $ and $ H $ are two different spaces, and I write \begin{equation}\langle{\phi( x_1 ) }, {\phi ( x_1) } \rangle_H  \quad \quad \langle{\tilde \phi(y_1 ) }, {\tilde \phi ( y_2 ) } \rangle_{H'} \end{equation}
will be $ H = H'$?  And $  \phi  =\tilde \phi $?

Maybe it is a trivial question, but if someone could clarify these points it would be really appreciated

Comment: What does $-$ and $\|\cdot\|$ mean here?  In your setup so far, $X$ is just a set with no additional structure, so it doesn't make sense to subtract elements of $X$ or take their norms.  Do you want for $X,Y$ to have some extra structure?

Comment: you can consider X and Y metric spaces, endowed with distance (reference paper: A Kernel Two-Sample Test, Arthur Gretton)

Comment: So let $X = \mathbb{R}$ and let $Y$ be a single point.  Then $H$ is infinite-dimensional, $H'$ is one-dimensional, and they are not in any sense the same.

Comment: As Nate pointed out, your question as stated does not make a lot of sense. Try to explain why you would like to "compare" those two spaces (feature and label) and what they have in common (except the expression for K).